# How to make strong assumptions?

Tags: evaluation, assumptions, variable

Or put in another way, how to make a variable behave as it belongs to a specific domain, even outside the use of simplify or other commands alike?

For example:

`Re[u]` returns `Re[u]` because the kernel cannot tell upfront that `u` is real.
Even after setting `$Assumptions = u ∈ Reals`, a call to `Re[u]` keeps returning `Re[u]`. A call to `Re[u] // Simplify` works.

But it would be simpler to make a variable behave always like assumed without the need to a call to `Simplify`. On the other hand a call to `Re[π]` returns `π` directly.

Is there a way to make variables behave like π does in the example above?

Comment: What you are proposing doesn't make a lot a sense in  _Mathematica_, where variables are just symbols and don't have any facility for carrying meta data such as type information. How would your idea of strong assumptions handle a variable that was given the strong assumption of being an integer, when that variable was bound to a complex value with `Set` at a later time?

Comment: Thank you for your interest and helpful insights. Well I certainly don't know how to answer that. But there is a point in that question I made. Even though Pi is a symbol, it behaves like a real. Is the symbol Pi a constant or a function to the kernel? How could I define a symbol of my own and tell the kernel my symbol belongs to a specified domain?

Answer (score 2):

Trivially, in this case you can use `Re[x] ^= x`.  However, you can't use upvalues with expressions like `Sqrt[Pi^2]` (which evaluates to `Pi`).

You could use `$Post` and `Refine`, but it's sort of a hack.

```
$Post = Refine[#, x \[Element] Reals] &
Re[x] (* x *)
Sqrt[x^2] (* Abs[x] *)
```

Note that this system isn't very flexible.  If you want to add another assumption, you need to reset `$Post`, remembering every previous assumption as well.  Perhaps something like:

```
addAssumption[expr_] := ($Assumptions = $Assumptions && expr;
                         $Post = Refine[#, $Assumptions] &)
```

Again, this is sort of a hacky way to do it.  I would recommend just using `Simplify`, `Refine`, or `ComplexExpand` where you need it instead.